# Finiteness property of fundamental groups 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. Let $X/K$ be a smooth variety. Is it true that the \'etale fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$ is topologically finitely generated.

I know that the answer is ``yes'' in the following two cases:

1) $X/K$ is proper.

2) $\dim(X)=1$. (In this case we can write down a presentation of $\pi_1(X)$ very explicitly.)

Can there anything go wrong in the general case? (It would be wonderful to have a reference which one can simply quote.)

Comment: Yes. Use the finite generation for the topological fund. grp (by
using finite triangulability of complex varieties) + the comparison
theorem SGA1 exp XII cor 5.2.

Comment: @Donu: can it be proved 'purely algebraicly'?

Comment: Mariano, I don't know of a purely algebraic argument, but it would certainly be interesting. As an aside, I might point out that the "wild" part of $\pi_1(\matbb{A}^1)$ in positive characteristic need not be finitely generated.

Comment: @Donu: This only covers the case $K = \mathbb{C}$, right? Or can we generalize this using model theory?

Comment: Martin, in general, you can choose alg. closed fields $K\supset K_0\subset \mathbb{C}$ so that $X$ is defined over $K_0$.
You  would need to verify that the (tame) fundamental group is unchanged in the process. This may require digging through SGA and/or 
supplying a proof.  

Comment: Donu's argument works by the invariance of the etale $pi_1$ under base-change of algebraically closed fields in characteristic zero. I believe the required specialization argument can be found in Serre's lectures on Galois theory. The key point is that $\pi_1(X\times Y)=\pi_1(X)\times \pi_1(Y)$, which fails in positive characteristic. An amusing (or vexing) fact is that an 'algebraic proof', in any reasonable sense, of finite-generation is unknown even for curves.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Dono Arapura, for explaining how one proves this statement, using the Riemann existance theorem in SGA1.

I mention for the sake of completeness: Today in the morning, I found that there is a SGA-reference for my question as it stands above: SGA 7.1, II.2.3.1. (I was surprised, that it is SGA 7.1, not SGA 1.)